# Crossword-style rebus puzzle

Tags: word, rebus, cryptic-crosswords, crossword-clues

The following image represents a word, in a way that makes sense in American English but not in British English.

[image: rebus]

What is the word?

Hint:

> describe the image in a way that would make sense as a clue in a cryptic crossword. The crossword entry which would be given by that clue is the word you need.

Comment: Is it a Russian word?

Comment: @JoeZ. That would be telling! ;-)

Comment: Gray Z gazing, (not grazing)

Comment: @Jiminion This is more or less [Mark Peters's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10784/5373). No joy, but probably one of the closest yet!

Comment: Gray N mirrored. Gray N turned.  Gray N reversed.

Comment: @Jiminion "Gray N turned" is very good. Post an answer, quick!

Comment: OK, but I don't really get it.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.

Comment: Great puzzle @randal'thor!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

> Gray N turned.  So turning ==> anagram.
>  So that would be :  Angry!

Comment: "Gray N turned" is the correct answer for the crossword clue. What single word could this refer to?

Comment: OK, I think I got it....

Comment: Congratulations! :-D You have indeed got it.

Comment: It would have been more helpful in the beginning if the N were indeed *turned* and not *mirrored*.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - It _is_ turned, about an axis parallel to the two uprights that goes through the midpoint.

Answer (score 5):

Best I can do is

> silvery

because

> it's a silver-ish "И" (which is pronounced [ˈi] in Russian)

Comment: OK, this is a good alternative solution, so +1. The one I have in mind is cleverer though, so I'll edit the question slightly - I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the OP's comments, I'm guessing it's *not*:

> Easy: И ("ee" in Russian) + Z ("zee" in American English)

But it's likely that it is:

> Some word or phrase containing "zee" (which is why it doesn't make sense in British English).

Comment: +1 for a good try that meets the American English criterion, but the colour is also relevant (and why Z as well as the Russian letter?)

Comment: Just spotted your comment to the other answer :-)

Comment: For the moment, I'll neither confirm nor deny whether "zee" is involved. That may change if it stays unsolved for too long ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Another thought I had was:

> Overgraze

Because

> it's a gray "z" that's been turned over?

Though I think this would work even better in British/Canadian English:

> Overgra**zed**

Comment: Getting closer ... you've got the right colour but the wrong letter.

Answer (score 3):

Second attempt:

Take into account my first answer. Then.. put in the Crossword aspect and we get:

> Against the Grain!

Comment: Now you're getting further away. As stated in the question, the answer is a single word.

Comment: Oh drat! Ah well

Answer (score 3):

Based on Uri Zarfaty's idea, it might be

> CRAZY:
>  gray letter Z = gray "zee" (in American English) = "crazy"

Comment: But it's not a Z; the orientation is wrong. There's more you need to take into account... Also no homophones are involved.

Answer (score 3):

"A gray N backwards (or turned around) is correct", so I am guessing

> Nyarga, which appears to be a place in Russia.

The difference b/w British and U.S. is

> the spelling of gray (grey is British).

Answer (score 2):

Given the numerous hints through other answers I'm going to say:

> Grainy

Since they color is

> gray

Plus:

> The N that I see

Plus:

> double ee from the

Russian (and to my eyes) backward N

Comment: You and Duncan are the closest yet! +1. Recall the title of the puzzle though - how might you describe this rebus as a crossword clue?

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Greenback

Because:

> It's a grey "n" that's backwards (taking some liberality with pronunciation of "grey")

And (US vs. Britain):

> "Greenback" is US slang for money but doesn't mean anything to Brits

Comment: A gray N backwards (or turned around) is correct, but the answer isn't. +1; you're getting closer!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> organize

Because in British English it would be:

> organise.  I'm pretty sure it's a play on -ize and -ise, even if that's not the word.

Update:

> Make that 'reflection'  (vs. reflexion)

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree here, I'm afraid. With so many answers, it's probably time for me to add a new hint to the question soon.

Answer (score 0):

The word is

> zig-zag

because

> it's an image of a zig-zag.

Comment: It's not that simple! :-p The exact shape and colour are significant. You're a crossword-writer, so you should be able to get this.